# PHP sleep and broadcasting to a channel

Tags: php

I need to broadcast to some users (android application) listening to a channel and ask them to post their location, hence I wait 5 seconds and in this period they will post their lat/lon location and after this time I will search for something based on this result.

To do so I use `sleep()` function. The PHP will wait and return results when the script is completed. I would like to know what is the PHP behavior in broadcasting? Does PHP broadcast after `5 seconds` or no, it immediately broadcasts and doesn't wait for `5 seconds` ?

Comment: How you implemented `broadcast`? If it's on same process and calling first broadcast and then sleep, then it will execute immediately, if first sleep and then broadcast, then after 5 secs.

Comment: @Justinas First broadcast then sleep, but when I print something on browser before sleep, it waits 5 seconds.

Comment: Because `sleep` stops script execution, so also output is delayed to be sent to browser. If your broadcast is socket based, then there should be no delay

Comment: The php sleep() function delays the execution of the script at the point where the function is called for the specified time. Then place your broadcast call before or after the sleep function.